# Consulting Interview Fee Refund -- No response (2+ months)

Tags: interviewing, travel, expenses

Attended a Consulting Interview for one of the offices of a firm outside of NA/EU.

Got an offer, and had to deny since the compensation was lower than I expected given the distance I had to travel, and they didn't have the flexibility to negotiate. The recruiter stated prior to my accepting the interview that I would get back my interview fees (~$500 USD). Interview fees included my flight to the city, as well as transportation (Uber) to and from the interview location. I paid this upfront to attend the interview, as I was told that it would be refunded.

After 8 emails and 2+ months, I have not received a response for over a month since the last email, which stated that the finance team would get back to me with my refund. I emailed the partner I interviewed with yesterday, with no response. What is your advice?

Comment: @joeqwerty - It is the regional firm in the Middle East. You think it would work for international claims & for such a small fee?

Comment: Given the location of the firm the best you can do is write this off as a lesson learned.  Never pay your own airfare/hotel for a job interview.  If they really want to see you in person then they'll pay for it.

Comment: Yet more proof that talk means nothing.  A sad tale.

Comment: Called the complaints hotline, and will send them a Demand for Payment letter by Monday.

Answer (score 3):

The recruiter is the one that made the promise to you.
Start leaning on that person and their firm, you'll have better luck.

*Unless* they've provided you with a bunch of good potential opportunities... in which case just drop it altogether instead of burning that bridge.